# How to solve returning an array into an empty array Java

Tags: java, arrays, reference

I keep getting this error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException     at
>   BattleshipCMDGame.GenerateShips(BattleshipCMDGame.java:33)    at
>   BattleshipCMDGame.main(BattleshipCMDGame.java:7)

All I want to do is return the newly created class type array in my method into an empty array created in the main method. Here is my code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class BattleshipCMDGame
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Ship[] ship = GenerateShips(3);
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    for (int i = 0; i < ship.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(ship[i].GetName() + " : Location - " + ship[i].GetLocation());
    }
}

public static Ship[] GenerateShips(int numShips)
{
    Ship[] ship = new Ship[numShips];
    Random rand = new Random();
    int randLoc;
    String prevRands = "";
    String randToString = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < ship.length; i++)
    {
        randLoc = 1 + rand.nextInt(7);
        randToString = Integer.toString(randLoc);

        for (int z = 0; z < ship.length; z++)
        {
            prevRands = "";

            if (ship[z].GetLocation() != 0)
            {
                prevRands += Integer.toString(ship[z].GetLocation());
            }
        }

        while (prevRands.contains(randToString))
        {
            randLoc = 1 + rand.nextInt(7);
            randToString = Integer.toString(randLoc);
        }

        ship[i] = new Ship("Ship no. " + (Integer.toString(i)), randLoc);
    }

    return ship;
}
}
```

Comment: As noted with the migration, implementation questions are best dealt with on SO rather than P.SE.  Questions of working with [null pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern), or the best choice of passing back null vs an empty ArrayList, or asking about points of the [The Billion Dollar Mistake](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Null-References-The-Billion-Dollar-Mistake-Tony-Hoare) would be more appropriate for P.SE (though look, there are other questions on this topic).

Comment: As an aside, particular to this code, please look at [StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) rather than doing `prevRands += Integer.toString(...);` You are likely creating and discarding lots of unnecessary strings.

Answer (score 3):

```
if (ship[z].GetLocation() != 0)
```

ship[z] is empty (null), so that's why you get the error.
You need to fill yout *ship* array first.

The important thing is: *ship* array stores *references* not *objects*, so that's why you need to fill it first. So

```
Ship[] ship = new Ship[10]
```

stores 10 *Ship* references (which starts as *null*), the actual Ship objects you need to assign by yourself.

Answer (score 3):

You have created the array in this line:

```
Ship[] ship = new Ship[numShips];
```

But all elements are `null`, so a `NullPointerException` results on this line:

```
if (ship[z].GetLocation() != 0)
```

You need to assign `Ship` objects to locations in your array, something like this:

```
ship[z] = new Ship();
```

Comment: Yeah, I actually solved the mistake on my own and you are right. Instead I just created a int count variable and increment it everytime I actually assign a ship var to a new ship object. I replaced a number in a for loop with count, that way it knows how many ships objects actually have reference from the array.

Answer (score 2):

You should initialize every element of the array:

```
ship[z] = new Ship();
```

Btw, you should use method names that starts with lower case, that's the standard